# jquery .html() how to render twice

Tags: jquery

I am passing a php string which contains html special characters, such as `&lt;div class=&quot;myclass` ... 
When I pass it to .html() it render it to actual html code but doesnt format it. the example above will be

```
"div class = "myclass"
```

Looks like I need to render the content again .html  but i am getting a blank page. This is my code

```
var htmlStr = $().html(Myobject.variable);
$("div.container").html(htmlStr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
var post_html = '&lt;div class=&quot;myclass&quot; &gt; stuff &lt;/div&gt;';

var html = post_html.replace(/&(lt|gt|quot);/g, function($0){
    switch($0){
        case '&lt;': return '<';
        break;
        case '&gt;': return '>';
        break;
        case '&quot;': return '"';
        break;       
    }
});
```

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/SUXkm/

Comment: thanks , i took another approach by placing in a function. But im wondering if there's a safer way? I want to make sure i encode all possible special character. Is there an existing function?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I would try and HTML encode the content on the server before sending it to the client.  Unfortunately JavaScript does not have a built in HTML encode/decode function but there is a library that someone has written that attempts to do this:

http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode

http://www.strictly-software.com/scripts/downloads/encoder.js